# Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Why would I be getting invalid for this? Version 1 works fine but for some reason I can't get this to load.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "islandsound_vowpal_wabbit_test",
      "image": "islandsound/vowpal_wabbit_test",
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 26542,
          "containerPort": 26542
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`AWSEBDockerrunVersion` version `2` is not supported by single container platforms, create an environment with a multi container platform and deploy to it.

To create a multi container platform from the CLI, you can run: `eb create --elb-type application -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.15.2 running Multi-container Docker 18.06.1-ce (Generic)"`

Comment: This is correct, but the exact platform is continually updated here (a new version comes out about every month): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.mcdocker

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here:

[multicontainer vs single container Dockerrun version](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221802)

> ... the issue is because the environment created is using a "Single
>   Container" platform ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a multi-container docker instance, you must select it when creating your environment.

Through AWS portal
Platform: Docker
Platform branch: Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux
Platform version: (recommended)